# Sending an email from WordPress through REST API with an Axios call

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, axios, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/nandomoreirame/5966bc4b12588904c214277328ba701a) to send an email from WordPress through the REST API.

My `Vue`-based front end is posting form data to WordPress using an Axios `put()` call:

```
sendEmail () {
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('contact_name', this.contactName)
  formData.append('contact_email', this.contactEmail)
  formData.append('contact_message', this.contactMessage)
  this.$axios.$put(`${this.baseUrl}/wp-json/contact/v1/send`, formData)
    .then((res) => {
      this.success = true
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this.$toast.error(err.response)
    })
}
```

I suppose the code above is correct, and that the issue lies on the WordPress side:

Functions.php:

```
function sendContactMail(WP_REST_Request $request) {
  $response = array(
    'status' => 304,
    'message' => 'There was an error sending the form.'
  );
  $parameters = $request->get_json_params();
  if (count($_POST) > 0) {
    $parameters = $_POST;
  }
  $siteName = wp_strip_all_tags(trim(get_option('blogname')));
  $contactName = wp_strip_all_tags(trim($parameters['contact_name']));
  $contactEmail = wp_strip_all_tags(trim($parameters['contact_email']));
  $contactMessage = wp_strip_all_tags(trim($parameters['contact_message']));    
  if (!empty($contactName) && !empty($contactEmail) && !empty($contactMessage)) {
    $subject = "(New message sent from site $siteName) $contactName <$contactEmail>";
    $body = "<h3>$subject</h3><br/>";
    $body .= "<p><b>Name:</b> $contactName</p>";
    $body .= "<p><b>Email:</b> $contactEmail</p>";
    $body .= "<p><b>Message:</b> $contactMessage</p>";
    if (send_email($contactEmail, $contactName, $body)) {
      $response['status'] = 200;
      $response['message'] = 'Form sent successfully.';
    }
  }
  return json_decode(json_encode($response));
  exit();
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'contact/v1', '/send', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'sendContactMail'
  ));
});
```

However, I have no idea how to troubleshoot the issue, because whichever problem is occuring here doesn't produce any input that I can see (I don't have access to server PHP log unfortunately).

Any idea about what's wrong in my code or how I could troubleshoot it?

Just in case below is the code of the `send_email()` function as well:

```
function send_email($form_email, $form_name, $form_message) {
  $email_subject = 'Message from '. get_bloginfo('name') . ' - ' . $form_email;
  $headers = "From: '" . $form_name . "' <" . $form_email . "> \r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($form_email) . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8";
  $email_message = '<html><body>';
  $email_message .= "<table>";
  $email_message .= "<tr><td>NAME: </td><td>" . $form_name . "</td></tr>";
  $email_message .= "<tr><td>MESSAGE: </td><td>" . $form_message . "</td></tr>";
  $email_message .= "</table>";
  $email_message .= "</body></html>";
  $email_message = nl2br($email_message);
  wp_mail('me@gmail.com', $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: can you stand up your own php site with these functions and debug that?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Did you make it work? I think that it may be caused by axios sending PUT request not the POST(which you declared in PHP)

Comment: Is me@gmail.com a real email? Also note that Gmail has a habit of putting mail FROM you TO you into SPAM.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in your axios put request. your form was not submitted correctly to the server due to missing header:

```
this.$axios.$put(`${this.baseUrl}/wp-json/contact/v1/send`, formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
.then((res) => {
  this.success = true
})
.catch((err) => {
  this.$toast.error(err.response)
})
```

i debugged it via more parameters in your wordpress function request response. i saw that all the form parameters where missing, so i investigated on that end and viola: its working now.